# Connect JSP and EJB

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How can I connect JSP pages and Enterprise JavaBeans?

1. Lookup the EJBs from within a JSP, but use the EJBs from within a basic JavaBean?
2. Lookup and use the EJBs from a separate business delegate. The JavaBeans that work with JSP pages are clients to these business delegates and know nothing about EJB specifics?
3. Lookup and use the EJBs from within a JSP page, but only as remote references?
4. Lookup the EJBs from within a servlet, delegating usage to specific JSP pages?

Comment: Your question ist far too broad. Technically all four approaches will work. It's a design question. @Santosh provided all the details you need. Common approaches are #2 and #4.

Answer (score 2):

Option #4 is the most appropriate when used with Delegates. Essentially what you need is [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) where in each layer is responsible for some specific functions.

- EJBs process the data and act as business components offering services via standard interfaces
- Delegates dealing with EJB and shielding any entities from details of lookup and invocation of EJB.
- Servlet invoke the business methods via *Delegates* and then pass the control to JSP along with data obtained from Delegate (eventually from EJB)
- JSP rendering the view based on the data passed by servlets .

  This is essentially an [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern and one of the standard recommended approaches. Please see refer to these links [1](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/guidelines/designing_enterprise_applications_2e/app-arch/app-arch2.html), [2](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/despat/).